# MERN Application is not storing session

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, cors, express-session

My MERN application is failing to store the session on the browser.  The backend is being hosted on Heroku and the client is being hosted by Vercel.  When I switch over to localhost, it works as expected, but on deployment, it fails to store any sessions.  If I try to log in a user, it will pass the authentication, but it won't store a session on my browser.

I get this error:

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/user' from origin 'https://myapp-client.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Here is what I have.

Server.js:

```
const url = process.env.MONGO_DB_URL

mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
})

const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'))
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('connected to mongo database')
})

const app = express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(
  mongoSanitize({
    replaceWith: '_',
  })
)
app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://192.168.1.14:3000', 'https://myapp-client.vercel.app'],
    credentials: true,
  })
)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// express session middleware

const store = MongoStore.create({
  mongoUrl: url,
  secret: process.env.MONGO_SECRET,
  touchAfter: 24 * 60 * 60,
})

store.on('error', err => {
  console.log(err)
})

app.use(
  session({
    store,
    name: 'rfts',
    secret: process.env.MONGO_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
  })
)

app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET))

// passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

And on the client, I use this to make calls to the server:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const macUrl = 'http://192.168.1.14:3001'
const localUrl = 'http://localhost:3001'
const herokuUrl = 'https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com'

const axiosCall = axios.create({
  baseURL: herokuUrl,
  withCredentials: true,
})

export default axiosCall
```

ANY advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience with heroku deploy. But in my experience, the origin url should be matched with the first element of cors[] array.
Please try this in backend code:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://myapp-client.vercel.app', 'http://192.168.1.14:3000'], credentials: true, methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'] }));
```

The order of elements in origin: array will be changed according to the app location: localhost or live site.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't do anything. Thank you very much for the assistance though!

Comment: I had same problem before. But my express server and react frontend used same IP address. So I am not sure about your problem.